# Can I repot one of these stalks separately?

Tags: repotting

I have this plant:

[image: plant]

In theory I would like to separate one of those stalks and repot it in its own pot; however, I'm not sure whether these are separate plants or three stalks growing from the same root. So my question is:

1. Is there a way to determine ahead of time whether these are separate plants or one plant?
2. If they are one plant, can I safely separate one stalk for separate repotting?

Comment: This is a dracaena reflexa and it has three separate stalks.  Careful work can split them up.Or you could cut a stalk and root it in water as they propagate easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it out of the pot and carefully remove some of the compost. It should be obvious if the stems all join together underground, or if each stem has its own roots (which will all be tangled up together as they grew out into the pot).

If the stems have separate roots, there should be no problem in separating it into three plants. Just try to do the minimum amount of damage to it.

For a large plant growing in the ground, often the easiest way is just to chop the whole root system into several pieces with a sharp knife or even with a spade, but potted plants may need a bit more care!